# How to validate white space in django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

#### forms.py

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Phone_info
        fields = ['name1','number1','name2','number2','name3','number3','emergency','emergency_number']
```

I need to validate the following fields: `name1,name2,name3,emergency` for empty space. Other validation I did in a single `clean()` method. How do I validate white space?

Comment: Do you mean the `name1` field cannot contain any whitespace?

Comment: name1,name2,name3 and emergency field cannot contain white space

Comment: Why not just strip out any space in the clean method for each field rather than depending on the user to properly format the input? It would save the user a step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write custom clean method for every individual fields on form:

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Phone_info
        fields = [
            'name1','number1','name2',
            'number2','name3','number3',
            'emergency','emergency_number'
        ]

    def clean_name1(self):
        name1 = self.cleaned_data['name1']
        if ' ' in name1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('name1 should not contain any space')
        return name1
```

Comment: how to write white space validation for all fields in clean() method.